# How do you search around any index in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm making a program that takes in a 2D array of 5x5, and lists all the characters around any given index of the array. For example, if I input list[1][1], it will give the indexes: [0][0], [0][1], [0][2], [1][0], [1][2], [2][0], [2][1] ,[2][2].

I can print out all the letters around the indexes except for the ones on the edges such as index [0][0]. I can't seem to figure out how to get past that.

```
 private static void checkSurrounding(char[][] list, int x, int y) {
    for(int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
        for(int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
            if(!(dx == 0 && dy == 0)) {
                System.out.print(list[x + dx][y + dy]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is there an example of an input with unexpected output?

Comment: When I input x and y as (0, 0), or any value that makes the index on the edge, it returns: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: what do you think would happen if `x` was 10000?  You have to do both upper and lower bounds checking

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if the input is an edge? Should it give fewer outputs, wrap around to the other side, or something else?

Comment: Would I have to give each side of the edge different bound checkings?

Comment: the expected behavior is to print the characters that it is touching. For example, list[0][0] should print out [0][1], [1][0], and [1,1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct! You exclude the middle point here:

```
 private static void checkSurrounding(char[][] list, int x, int y) {
    for(int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
        for(int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
            if(!(dx == 0 && dy == 0)) {
                System.out.print(list[x + dx][y + dy]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The only thing you miss is to avoid getting out of bounds. Just make sure that you do not get out of bounds and it should work impeccably:

```
 private static void checkSurrounding(char[][] list, int x, int y) {
    for(int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
        if ((x + dx >= 0) && (x + dx < list.length)) {
            for(int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
                if ((y + dy >= 0) && (y + yd < list[x + dx].length) && (!(dx == 0 && dy == 0))) {
                    System.out.print(list[x + dx][y + dy]);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ahh it works! I couldn't figure out how to ensure I did not go out of bounds, thank you!

Comment: @RandomJavaCoder you are welcome, the most important is to make sure you understand that your solution was almost correct as it was. Of course you are a beginner, but you were not far from the solution. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider marking it as the correct answer.